# Query to pick preferred available row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use SQL server.
I currently have a table which contains several items, some of them have a price and some not.
However some of them have several prices columns: “Commercial price”, “Current price”, “New price”

It is possible that for some of the items not all of the 3 pricing columns above exist, and some only have “Current price” and the rest is NULL.

So I need the query to check which one of the prices columns exist/isn’t null, by the following “priority”
New price > Current price > Commercial price
(That means that if “New price” doesn’t exist or is NUll, the query will pick the price from “Current price”)

And in the end to add a row/columns which is named “Total” and calculates all the prices together.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COALESCE([New price],[Current price],[Commercial price]) as Price
```

For the last part you could add a UNION with another select (possibly grouped by product or whatever), something like:

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL([New Price], 0) + ISNULL([Current price], 0) + ISNULL(Commercial price], 0) AS Total
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. And in case a have a column which is named “ ID” (of the item) and I want to list it as well? And then add the total number of items and the total price of all...

Comment: Just add it -> SELECT ID, COALESCE([New price],[Current price],[Commercial price]) as Price

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, SUM(ISNULL([New Price], 0) + ISNULL([Current price], 0) + ISNULL(Commercial price], 0) AS TotalPrice FROM YOURTABLE
GROUP BY ID
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(ID), SUM(ISNULL([New Price], 0) + ISNULL([Current price], 0) + ISNULL(Commercial price], 0) AS TotalPrice FROM YOURTABLE
```